# Commutator of two normal subgroups with trivial intersections

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

So I tried looking everywhere but I'm really lost with this proof. I need to to show that:

> Let $H$, $K$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$, satisfying $H\cap K = \{e\}$. Let $h\in H$, $k \in K$.
>
> (a) Prove that the commutator $w = hkh^{-1}k^{−1}$ satisfies $w \in H$ and $w \in K$. Then conclude that $w = e$
>
> (b) Prove that $hk = kh$, for all $h \in H$, $k \in K$.

Comment: For formatting, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

(a) Since $K$ is normal $hkh^{-1}\in K$ and therefore $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in K$. The same argument proves that $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H$.

(b) $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}=e\implies hkh^{-1}=k\implies hk=kh$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a), note that $hkh^{-1} \in K$ since $K$ is normal.  As $K$ is a subgroup, you now see that $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in K$.  The claim on $H$ membership is proved the same way.  Since $w \in H \cap K = \{e\}$ there is no choice but $w=e$.

Answer (score 0):

Additional but useful fact: since the subgroups $H$ and $K$ are normal, also $HK=\{hk : h \in H, k \in K\}$ is a normal subgroup. If $H \cap K = \{e\}$, then $HK \cong H \times K$, the *direct product* of $H$ and $K$.